# How to create and use custom build flags in Bazel?

Tags: bazel

I've a rule with a conditional attribute:

```
some_rule(
  name = "my_rule",
  some_attr = select({
    ":ts_diagnostics_mode_extended": ["--extendedDiagnostics"]
  }),
)
```

and with the config setting:

```
config_setting(
   name = "ts_diagnostics_mode_extended",
   values = { "define": "ts_diagnostics_mode=extended_diagnostics" }
)
```

However, when building with `bazel build :my_target --define ts_diagnostics_mode=extended_diagnostics` I get
`Configurable attribute "some_attr" doesn't match this configuration (would a default condition help?).`

What's missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--define` flags are handled specially by `config_setting`, via [`define_values`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#config_setting.define_values), because they are multi-valued.  I think this will work:

```
config_setting(
    name = "ts_diagnostics_mode_extended",
    define_values = { "ts_diagnostics_mode": "extended_diagnostics" }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

While `define_values` indeed works, your original example with `values` should also work. `define_values` is only necessary when you want the `config_setting` to have multiple entries.

See this line in the [define_values](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/be/general.html#config_setting.define_values) documentation:

> `--define` can still appear in `values` with normal flag syntax, and can be mixed freely with this attribute as long as dictionary keys remain distinct.

Comment: You're right. When testing again with the original example, it works but only when including the default condition, `//conditions:default`. Same goes for when using `define_values`.
Seems a bit strange to having to include the default condition in the setting configuration for it to work though.